# Pageview Triggers not firing on gtm.dom or gtm.load | Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, eventtrigger

I am fairly new to Web Design/Web Development, so I apologize if I am missing a simple solution to my problem.

I have Google Tag Manager installed (i think properly) on my WordPress website, and I can see it when checking with Google Tag Assistant. However, none of my other tags are appearing on Tag Assistant, and when looking in the preview mode I see this:
[GTM Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19lSI.png)

And I when I look for errors I see this:
[GTM Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtNgR.png)

It appears that '_event' value is equal to gtm.js in both DOM and Window Loaded, when it should be gtm.dom and gtm.load respectively (i think?)

Does anyone have any idea what I can do? Let me know if I need to include more information.

EDIT: I should state that all of the tags are fired in 'Container Loaded' except for the Contact Form submission tag

Answer (score 0):

Your first picture shows that tags are fired, and the second picture does not show errors - you have selected the DOM Ready event in the preview pane, and your tags have already been fired on the container loaded event. The red crossed in the trigger preview indicate that the conditions for firing are not met, which is due to you looking at the gtm.dom event (if you click container loaded instead, you get information on gtm.js. You can see which event you currently inspect, since this is displayed in blue).

If you don't see your tags in Tag Assistant than you might have forgotten to publish (also Tag Assistant is not the most reliable tool to start with). You should rather look in the realtime view of you GA account to see if your hits show up (or in the network tab in your browser).

Comment: When I look at the Realtime View in Google Analytics, none of my goals have counted, even when I have self-triggered them (for example, I have a destination goal on an 'order-received' page, but after visiting that page, no conversions in GA are counted, it has also been several days of trying to trigger the goal) | Now what is interesting is that even though Tag Assistant does not show my GA tag, my GA account appears to be connected to the domain, as in Realtime I can see when I am browsing the site.